# How to use Okhttpclient object between activites using dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have created a EmailComponent interface which has 2 modules EmailModule and Networkmodule , I am trying to share Email object and Okhttpclient object between activites . In `ActivityA` I did:

```
    EmailComponent component = DaggerEmailComponent.builder()
    .emailModule(new EmailModule())
    .netWorkModule(new NetWorkModule()).build();
    component.Email().sendEmail();
```

This is working fine. My question is how can I inject them into `ActivityB` Without calling again DaggerEmailComponent build code?

If i try using field injection in `ActivityB` like this code below it crashes.

```
     @Inject Email email
     email.sendMail(); // App crash.
```

Is what am trying to accomplish possible? If Yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if some one giving minus vote they should explain why

Comment: To avoid making the EamilComponent again and again you may make a Base Activity and move the code of making the component there. Or you may make a subclass of `Application` and make a static component there which can then be used from anywhere in the app. You must be getting NPE as the field may not have been initialized.

Comment: Hi abdul thanks for the reply . i understand the way ur saying like singleton u can initiate and acces the component ryt, but my case is i want to use dagger2 @inject concept.. so that directly the Email object will be injected .

Comment: Yes. By doing so you will inject objects using `@Inject`. Create a method in your dagger component with your activity as a parameter then and call that method using the static EamilComponent in Application subclass just after the onCreate of the activity.

Comment: Hi Abul thanks it works .

Comment: Great! Maybe you can mark that as an accepted answer so that it might help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid making the `EamilComponent` again and again you may make a Base Activity and move the code of making the component there. Or you may make a subclass of `Application` and make a static component there which can then be used from anywhere in the app. You must be getting NPE as the field may not have been initialized.

For using static component from the `Application` subclass create a method in your dagger component with your base activity as a parameter and then call that method using the static EamilComponent in Application subclass just after the onCreate of the activity. You can even call the method in the component before onCreate.